# Better way to handle perl sockets to read/write to active proccess

Tags: perl, sockets, process, pipe

First of all I would thank you guys not offering a work around as a solution (although it would be cool to know other ways to do it). I was setting up tg-master project (telegram for cli) to be used by check_mk alert plugin. I found out that telegram runs on a stdin/stdout proccess so I tought it would be cool to "glue" it, so i wrote with a lot of building blocks from blogs and cpan the next 2 pieces of code. They already work (i need to handle broken pipes sometimes) but I was wondering if sharing this could come from some experts new ideas.

As you could see my code relies on a eval with a die reading from spawned process, and I know is not the best way to do it. Any suggestions? :D

Thank you guys

**Server**

```
use strict;

use IO::Socket::INET;
use IPC::Open2;
use POSIX;
our $pid;

use sigtrap qw/handler signal_handler normal-signals/;

sub signal_handler {
    print "what a signal $!\nlets kill $pid\n";
    kill 'SIGKILL', $pid;
    #die "Caught a signal $!";
}

# auto-flush on socket
$| = 1;
# creating a listening socket
my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET(
    LocalHost => '0.0.0.0',
    LocalPort => '7777',
    Proto     => 'tcp',
    Listen    => 5,
    Reuse     => 1
);
die "cannot create socket $!\n" unless $socket;
print "server waiting for client connection on port 7777\n";
my ( $read_proc, $write_proc );

my ( $uid, $gid ) = ( getpwnam "nagios" )[ 2, 3 ];
POSIX::setgid($gid);    # GID must be set before UID!
POSIX::setuid($uid);

$pid = open2( $read_proc, $write_proc, '/usr/bin/telegram' );

#flush first messages;
eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "Timeout" };    # alarm handler
    alarm(1);
    while (<$read_proc>) { }
};
while (1) {
    my $client_socket  = $socket->accept();
    my $client_address = $client_socket->peerhost();
    my $client_port    = $client_socket->peerport();
    print "connection from $client_address:$client_port\n";

    # read until \n
    my $data = "";
    $data = $client_socket->getline();
    # write to spawned process stdin the line we got on $data
    print $write_proc $data;
    $data = "";

    eval {
        local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "Timeout" };    # alarm handler
        alarm(1);

        while (<$read_proc>) {
            $client_socket->send($_);
        }
    };
    # notify client that response has been sent
    shutdown( $client_socket, 1 );
}
$socket->close();
```

**Client**

```
echo "contact_list" | nc localhost 7777
```

or

```
echo "msg user#12345 NAGIOS ALERT ... etc" | nc localhost 7777
```

or

some other perl script =)

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to implement a script that performs both reads and writes from/to different handles, consider using `select` (the one defined as `select RBITS,WBITS,EBITS,TIMEOUT` in the documentation). In this case you will totally avoid using `alarm` with a signal handler in `eval` to handle a timeout, and will only have one loop with all of the work happening inside it.

Here is an example of a program that reads from both a process opened with `open2` and a network socket, not using `alarm` at all:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket;
use IPC::Open2;
use constant MAXLENGTH => 1024;

my $socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(
        Listen => SOMAXCONN,
        LocalHost => '0.0.0.0',
        LocalPort => 7777,
        Reuse => 1,
);

# accepting just one connection
print "waiting for connection...\n";
my $remote = $socket->accept();
print "remote client connected\n";

# simple example of the program writing something
my $pid = open2(my $localread, my $localwrite, "sh -c 'while : ; do echo boom; sleep 1 ; done'");

for ( ; ; ) {
        # cleanup vectors for select
        my $rin = '';
        my $win = '';
        my $ein = '';

        # will wait for a possibility to read from these two descriptors
        vec($rin, fileno($localread), 1) = 1;
        vec($rin, fileno($remote), 1) = 1;

        # now wait
        select($rin, $win, $ein, undef);

        # check which one is ready. read with sysread, not <>, as select doc warns
        if (vec($rin, fileno($localread), 1)) {
                print "read from local process: ";
                sysread($localread, my $data, MAXLENGTH);
                print $data;
        }
        if (vec($rin, fileno($remote), 1)) {
                print "read from remote client: ";
                sysread($remote, my $data, MAXLENGTH);
                print $data;
        }
}
```

In the real production code you will need to carefully check for errors returned by various function (socket creation, `open2`, `accept`, and `select`).

Comment: This code results on a crazy process, and doesn't allow client to exit.

The idea is to maintain a local daemon "alive" while handling many clients connecting, sending commands, receiving the response  and disconnecting.

./socket-play.pl 
waiting for connection...
remote client connected
read from remote client: kaboom
read from remote client: read from remote client: read from remote client: read from remote client: read from remote client: read from remote client: read from remote client: read from remote client: read from remote client: read from remote client: read from remote client: